# How to always get distant ancestor reference when loading descendent?

Tags: entities, nodes, views

I have a fairly large website with some complex relationships. One such string of relationships looks like this:

`region > counties > cities > locations > contacts`

Each level is the name of a content type. Each level is a parent with many children (except the last) connected via simple Entity Reference fields.

The `region` content type is central to the entire site. Users, custom permissions, custom layouts, every content type – it all revolves around the region in some way.

I have dozens of views on this site and as you might expect things get pretty ugly when trying to find out what region any of the descendent content types are associated with. To find the region for a given contact for instance, the relationship looks like this:

```
location for given contact >
city for given location >
county of given city >
region of given county
```

I'm really getting tired of making these long relationship trees in views. Of course, outside of views, I can write a function like `load_region_by_contact` or something, but I'm using the views UI quite a bit and I can't seem to find any way to store this set of relationships (and others) in a way that I can repeatedly reuse.

The data itself doesn't change too often and can be heavily cached, so I'm not opposed to the 'views of views' solution. I just don't know how to build it.